# JS: Is it possible to listen with a (tcp) socket on a dynamic address?

Tags: javascript, sockets, electron, runtime-error

*Is it Possible to listen with a (tcp) socket on a dynamic address?*
Like I want to use **my-website.net** insead of a public IP.

### **This is my Code:**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
  });
  server.listen('1337', 'my-website.net');
})
```

### I get this Error:

> Uncaught Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available
> *[IP Censored]*:1337
> at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (VM89 net.js:1301)
> at listenInCluster (VM89 net.js:1366)
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (VM89 net.js:1503)
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (VM101 dns.js:69)

(I forwared all Ports and it does work with 127.0.0.1)
What does the Error mean? that static dynamic IPs dont work?

Comment: Is the censored IP a valid IP for your hostname? Is it a local address like a `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x` address or something else? Is it one you recognize as belonging to your instance in any network context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, You got a dynamic ip and using some dynamic ip service like dyndns.org. There are 2 ways of doing it... first would be complicated, and You would have to check the address every few seconds then stop the server and listen on the ip You currently got. Not the best solution. Other would be to listen on `0.0.0.0` - that basically means to listen on every IP you got in the system. So if IP changes, it doesn't matter, as it will always listen to EVERY interface.

The error You are getting means that none of the network interfaces have that IP. Are You using router and getting local IP 192.x.x.x instead? Then You should setup the port forwarding on Your router and listen on local IP of Your adapter that connects to it.